# Is let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {}; the same as ...?

Tags: typescript

The typescript handbook has the following example:

```
// Validators to use
let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {};
validators["ZIP code"] = new ZipCodeValidator();
```

Is doing:

```
let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {};
```

The same as:

```
let validators = {};
validators["s"] = new StringValidator();
```

If you could elaborate on the details on how the syntax works that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is doing:
>
> ```
> let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {};
> ```
>
> The same as:
>
> ```
> let validators = {};
> validators["s"] = new StringValidator();
> ```

No, `let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {};` is different from `let validators = {};`.

---

What

```
let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {};
```

is doing is declaring an identifier with a type. What you're saying with the code above is: "I'm declaring the identifier `validators` and the type of this object can have any `string`, `s` as a key to the object (remember that javascript objects are just key-value pairs) and the value of the every key will be of type `StringValidator`.

If you remove the type annotation (anything on the right side of the `:`), you *not* given the object a type.

You can observe the difference when you highlight over the declariation in vs code. You'll get the type `{ [s: string]: StringValidator; }` if you add the type annotation, but if you remove it, you'll get `any`, meaning that object can be 'any' type.

Answer (score 1):

No, they're not the same.

The first one

```
let validators: { [s: string]: StringValidator; } = {};
```

declares a variable named `validators` whose type is `{ [s: string]: StringValidator; }` and whose value is `{}`. This type means that `validators` can be indexed by key (a string) to yield an instance of `StringValidator`. Note that `s` is a "dummy" variable whose actual name has no runtime effect; the name serves only to document the meaning of the indexer.

Note that no `StringValidator` object is instantiated. The final value of `validators` is an empty object.

The second one

```
let validators = {};
validators["s"] = new StringValidator();
```

first declares a variable named `validators` whose type is inferred to be `{}` (an object with no properties) and whose value is `{}`. It then instantiates a `StringValidator` object and assigns the result to the `s` property of `validators`.

The final value of `validators` is an object with a property named `s` that references a `StringValidator` object.